# Selenium Grid: Displaying "Could not start new session" after executing some test cases

Tags: session, timeoutexception, selenium4, java-15

We are using Selenium Grid, Hub and node configuration for parallel execution.

**Probelm**:

After executing some test scripts(execution duration is 54 min), getting below exception.

**org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException**

Selenium Version: 4.9.0
JDK: 15
WebDriverManager: 5.3.1
Junit: 4.12
Running Mode: Parallel
Node command:java -jar selenium-server-4.9.0.jar hub --session-request-timeout 5000
Hub Command: java -jar selenium-server-4.9.0.jar node --register-period 1000 --override-max-sessions true  --max-sessions 4

I have tried increasing --session-request-timeout 5000 to 7000 but after till 54 min test scripts are executing successfully but after 54min it's throwing above error.

We are expecting irrespective of duration(54 minutes)it should execute all the test scripts.

**Result:** After 54 min of test script execution, its throwing could not create new session